# P.R. Halmos subnormal paper

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

In several paper on subnormal and hyponormal operator, they cite :

> **P.R. Halmos**, "Normal dilations and extensions of operators", Summa Brasil. Math. 2 (1950),
>   125-134. MR 13, 359

as a reference, but I'm having trouble finding this paper in the internet.  I tried looking for the journal site, but I don't get anything . Does someone know how to find it, or can you please send it to me ?

Comment: Do you know the DOI of the paper?

Comment: no i don't have any more information